# Закрывается приложение node js на хостинге

Tags: node.js, express, хостинг

Использую CPANEL, создал приложение node JS, с использованием express. Если не обращаться к приложению то оно закрывается и на сайт попасть получается с большой задержкой ответа сервера. В разделе "ошибки"  вот такое сообщение: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process. Как мне Избавиться от закрытия процесса?

Comment: бесплатный хостинг?

Comment: хостинг платный

Comment: тогда что значит что оно закрывается, логи есть?

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4QXT/4qQqneL1W

Comment: а в разделе ошибки:
[ N 2019-04-21 09:31:42.6308 2734284/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1028 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 2737780, application /home/cp447585/kreditor.store (production)
[ N 2019-04-21 09:31:42.6289 2734284/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1028 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 2737780, application /home/cp447585/kreditor.store (production)